# SQL Return At least Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have SQL data in the following structure:

```
Car_Color  | Model_tag 
---------------------- 
  Green    | Fairytail1
  Red      | Tail2
  Blue     | Fairy3
  Green    | Hi3
  Green    | Test45
  Green    | Testing34
```

I would like to get the output as below that return the following query: Find all names of car_color that have at least **four** associated model_tag, and for these colors, the number of model_tags written in each car_color.

```
Car_Color  | number_of_tags
----------------------------
  Green    |  4
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT car, model_tag
FROM Model
```

**Problem is that this following query doesn't return any data.**

Answer (score 4):

Fix the aggregation logic:

```
SELECT c.car_color, COUNT(mt.tag_name) as numer_of_tags 
FROM Model m JOIN
     model_tag mt
     ON mt.tag_id = m.model_id JOIN
     car c
     ON c.car_color_id = m.model_id
GROUP BY c.car_color
HAVING COUNT(mt.tag_name) >= 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can get the desired output if you group model_tag.tag_name, try this :

```
SELECT car.car_color, COUNT (model_tag.tag_name) as numer_of_tags 
FROM Model
JOIN model_tag ON model_tag.tag_id = model.model_id
JOIN car ON car.car_color_id = model.model_id
GROUP BY car.car_color
HAVING COUNT(car.car_color_id)>=4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this also, I actually just copied answer above and put DISTINCT

```
SELECT c.car_color, COUNT(DISTINCT mt.tag_name) as numer_of_tags 
  FROM Model m JOIN
      model_tag mt
     ON mt.tag_id = m.model_id JOIN
      car c
      ON c.car_color_id = m.model_id
 GROUP BY c.car_color
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mt.tag_name) >= 4;
```